# CSS float on content inside an anchor or other inline elements

Tags: css, css-float, anchor, image, conventions

Let's say I have the following markup:

```
<li style="width: 200px;">
    <a href="....">
        <img style="width: 50px;" src="..." />
    </a>
    Lorem ipsum...
</li>
```

And that I would like the image to be floated to the left.

Should `float: left` be applied to the image tag or the anchor tag that contains it? Both are inline elements anyway. Is there a recommended practice or **convention** in regards to that?

EDIT: Perhaps I forgot to specify there's text present after the image, and the required result is the image should be aligned to the left of course with the text and the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating elements with non explicit width is unpredictable, so I would go with the image, or better yet would give the anchor an explicit width and make it block, to minimise any indirect changes.

Be aware though that if you float the image when the anchor isn't floated, the anchor will collapse to zero width (and height). This is because the image is taken out of the normal flow of the page when floated. if you float the anchor, this will happen to the parent of the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

The `img` tag is inline to the `a` tag, and since there's nothing else in it this makes little-to-no difference - similarly with floating, unless you have a wider width outer element than the inner element; the `a` element's display mode will be relative to its parent, too, so that's probably what you want.

Comment: 'unless you have a wider width than the inner element' - which elements are you referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to the container of any given element, the parent.

Comment: I made the code even more specific, please see the changes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depends, if it's a listing of images only and you want to float each of them, you might as well float the whole list-item.

Comment: Correct, but that's not the situation I was referring to (I updated the question with more information if you're interested).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you want to apply the class to the anchor link instead of the image is that like Asad said, applying the class to the image takes the anchor out of the flow of the page and removes its width and height.

The reason this is important is because when a user tabs through a page the entire element should be highlighted when :focused like this: http://cl.ly/fFwI

If you apply the class to the image you get this behavior: http://cl.ly/fFxh

If tab focus is important to you, apply the class to the anchor.